# Android permission ACCES_NETWORK_STATE bug?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-permissions

Im using Google V2 in my android app and it works good. Eclipse however is giving me this warning every time I run:

```
Please add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> into AndroidManifest.xml to ensure correct behavior under poor connectivity conditions.
```

But I already added this permission in my manifest and have this in my xml:

```
<!-- More usses permissions, this is inside the <manifest> but outside the <application> tag -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I think I've set it up correct but eclipse is still giving me this warning. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know why?

You have `android.permission.ACCES_NETWORK_STATE`, which is incorrect. The value is `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`, with two `S` characters in the `ACCESS` portion.

Comment: omg... Still I think its weird because I added it on the permissions tab of the manifest.